# Constructing a partition function for a gas-solid equilibrium in canonical ensemeble

Tags: physical-chemistry, statistical-mechanics

For a closed system at fixed N,V,T there is a solid in equilibrium with its vapor. I'm told that I can minimize the helmholtz free energy to find that the equilibrium condition is given by

$N_g = \frac{q_g}{q_s} $ Where $N_g$ is the Number of particles in the gas phase, and $q_s$ and $q_g$ are the partition functions for the solid and gas phase respectively.

I'm also given that $Q_s = q_s^{N_s}$.

I've attempted to solve $ \frac{\partial A}{\partial N_g} = 0$ to show this.

Since N,V,T are fixed I know it's a canonical ensemble and that $A = -kTln(Q)$.

What I'm unsure on is how to find the partition function Q.

In the Atkins and DePaula textbook there's a brief example of factorizing the molecular partition function to isolate the different contributions from vibration, rotation, etc. I'm unsure if this applies here. The textbook starts from finding the total energy of the system from a sum of its parts. I don't intuit that a solid-gas equilibrium should follow the same logic but nevertheless I tried continuing assuming this would work so then

$Q = Q_sQ_g$

I first tried with the gas particles distinguishable (so I wouldn't have to deal with a factorial in the derivative) and found

$Q_g = q_g^{N_g},  Q_s = q_s^{N-N_g}, Q = q_g^{N_g}q_s^{N-N_g}$ (since the total number of particles N is constant, $N = N_g + N_s$)

which gives

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial N_g} = 0 = -kT(ln(\frac{q_g}{q_s})) => \frac{q_g}{q_s} = 1 $

I then tried with an indistinguishable partition function for the gas phase

$Q_g = \frac{q_g^{N_g}}{N_g!}$

I'm less familiar with this math so I relied on wolfram alpha for the derivative which gives

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial N_g} = 0 = \frac{\Gamma(N_g+1)\psi^{(0)}(N_g+1)}{N_g!} - ln(\frac{q_g}{q_s})$

Before I go any further, is this how I should construct the partition function? Is there a text online that someone could point me to?

Comment: If I wanted to study this I'd look at the solid-state hydrogen storage of metal hydrides. I know metal hydrides have been extensively studied for making hydrogen powered vehicles. One nice feature is that if the pressure tank is ruptured all of the hydrogen isn't released and once to create a massive BOOM! However the hydrides do release the hydrogen fast enough to provide sufficient fuel to the vehicle.